# Skype white screen problem

Tags: 14.04, skype

I just installed the latest Skype and when I log in the chat log appears but when I click anything, everything disappears and all I can see is a white screen as shown in the image. I tried purging skype and reinstalling it. Restarted pc. Didn't work. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here (started on 11 jan 2018).
Purging and moving back to version 8.9.0.1 helped me.
Previous version repository: https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/

Comment: 8.9.0.1 is removed. You can try with version 8.10.0.4  (skypeforlinux_8.10.0.4_amd64.deb) .